# How come keyword ranking checkers are never accurate

Tags: keywords, google-ranking, rank-checkers

I am currently using a keyword ranking checker called authority lab. When I was using its test version, the rankings seemed accurate. Now I am paying for the professional version, only to find out the results are always completely different from the ones I checked myself (while checking for the rankings I did log out, so that would not be the problem).

I just wonder how these kind of tools works and why they are not accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tools are always a bit sketchy and require constant maintenance by the provider depending upon how the search engines change how information is queried by them. There are also other factors that can affect the results you get when testing an automated tool versus doing it manually such as:

i)Whether you are logged into your own account (personal search)

ii) Your location (local can get precedence)

iii) You are using the right search engine e.g. google.com vs. google.co.uk

The most reliable tool I use is Advanced Web Ranking. Let me be clear I actually dislike using it as its interface is terrible but as long as it is maintained with a subscription and you don't make to many automated queries it is generally accurate. It is by Caphyon.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hmmm, thx. I might give it a try